# <meta> tag in <asp:ContentPlaceholder> generates parser exception

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages, meta-tags, contentplaceholder

I've got a Web Form that uses a Master File.

I'm trying to have some of the Meta Tags to be set by default but overridable in the sub-files

I'm setting up the Main.Master file to look like this:

```
<head runat="server">    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pgTitle" runat="server"> 
        <meta id="mtaPgTitle" runat="server" class="pgTitle" content="DefaultTitle"/>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This creates a line in the Main.Master.designer.cs file that looks like this

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta mtaPgTitle;
```

However, when I try to run it, I get a Parser Error with the message

```
The base class includes the field 'mtaPgTitle', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).
```

We just recently upgraded to VS2010 from VS2008.  Is there a way to fix this short of manually combing through the designer files to revert the type back to HtmlGenericControl?  I've tried adding a fix to the various loading events, but the Parser Error seems to occur before any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a great article which might help you in developing dynamic html metatags for your pages ... [MetaTags in ASP.Net Master Pages and ContentPlaceholders](http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonconway/archive/2008/03/24/meta-tags-in-asp-net-using-masterpage-and-contentplaceholders.aspx)

Hope this helps!